# JSON child objects return undefined values

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON with different child objects (**scans**) shown below. I am trying print contents of child objects with javascript, it gives me an output 'undefined'.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jpavanaryan/sz5gkesh/

```
 alert(jsonobj.scans[0]);


 var jsonobj={
           "scan_id": "004d396404ae9343e1479689c05d02290babdf14f502b3437e247e02e74ba803-1490201685",
           "resource": "http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm",
           "url": "http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm",
           "response_code": 1,
           "scan_date": "2017-03-22 16:54:45",
           "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/url/004d396404ae9343e1479689c05d02290babdf14f502b3437e247e02e74ba803/analysis/1490201685/",
           "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object",
           "filescan_id": "fb2d9f058c2010c57f86a05ae33d282f33e3825290c66b8b120cd177416c6bdf-1489446422",
           "positives": 15,
           "total": 64,
           "scans":    {
              "CLEAN MX":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Rising":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "OpenPhish":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "VX Vault":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "ZDB Zeus":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "ZCloudsec":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "PhishLabs":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "unrated site"
              },
              "Zerofox":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "K7AntiVirus":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "SecureBrain":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Quttera":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "AegisLab WebGuard":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "MalwareDomainList":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site",
                 "detail": "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=helenphilwarnes.com"
              },
              "ZeusTracker":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site",
                 "detail": "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php?host=helenphilwarnes.com"
              },
              "zvelo":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Google Safebrowsing":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "FraudScore":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Kaspersky":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "BitDefender":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malware site"
              },
              "Opera":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malicious site"
              },
              "Certly":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "G-Data":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "C-SIRT":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "CyberCrime":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Websense ThreatSeeker":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "MalwarePatrol":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Webutation":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Trustwave":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malicious site"
              },
              "Web Security Guard":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "desenmascara.me":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "ADMINUSLabs":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Malwarebytes hpHosts":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Dr.Web":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "AlienVault":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Emsisoft":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "Malc0de Database":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site",
                 "detail": "http://malc0de.com/database/index.php?search=helenphilwarnes.com"
              },
              "malwares.com URL checker":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Phishtank":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "Malwared":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Avira":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "StopBadware":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "unrated site"
              },
              "Antiy-AVL":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "SCUMWARE.org":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malware site"
              },
              "FraudSense":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Comodo Site Inspector":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Malekal":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "ESET":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "Sophos":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malicious site"
              },
              "Yandex Safebrowsing":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site",
                 "detail": "http://yandex.com/infected?l10n=en&url=http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm"
              },
              "Spam404":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Nucleon":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Malware Domain Blocklist":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Blueliv":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Netcraft":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "malicious site"
              },
              "AutoShun":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "unrated site"
              },
              "ThreatHive":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "ParetoLogic":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Tencent":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "URLQuery":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "unrated site"
              },
              "Sucuri SiteCheck":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Fortinet":       {
                 "detected": true,
                 "result": "phishing site"
              },
              "ZeroCERT":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "Baidu-International":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              },
              "securolytics":       {
                 "detected": false,
                 "result": "clean site"
              }
           }
        };
```

Comment: Please include ALL of your code from jsfiddle, because if the jsfiddle ever disappears, so does the context of your question. Or better yet, post your code as a snippet, so it's runnable directly from your post. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to print it before you create the object?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scans` is another object and you're trying to reference an index. So when you do `scans[0]` - it's actually looking for the key `"0"` inside of `scans`, which doesn't exist. Use a key:

```
jsonobj.scans["VX Vault"].result
```

Dont know the keys? Then iterate with a `for in` loop:

```
for (var key in jsonobj.scans) {
    console.log(jsonobj.scans[key]);
}
```

Comment: I have more than 30 keys in JSON, so I was looking for some generic way for the iteration.

Comment: @Jadda -- See my example for how to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

The property `jsonobj.scans` is an associative array.  Each scan must be accessed by name `jsonobj.scans['scanname']` or can be enumerated using the `for ... in` construct.

```js
var jsonobj={
       "scan_id": "004d396404ae9343e1479689c05d02290babdf14f502b3437e247e02e74ba803-1490201685",
       "resource": "http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm",
       "url": "http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm",
       "response_code": 1,
       "scan_date": "2017-03-22 16:54:45",
       "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/url/004d396404ae9343e1479689c05d02290babdf14f502b3437e247e02e74ba803/analysis/1490201685/",
       "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object",
       "filescan_id": "fb2d9f058c2010c57f86a05ae33d282f33e3825290c66b8b120cd177416c6bdf-1489446422",
       "positives": 15,
       "total": 64,
       "scans":    {
          "CLEAN MX":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Rising":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "OpenPhish":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "VX Vault":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "ZDB Zeus":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "ZCloudsec":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "PhishLabs":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "unrated site"
          },
          "Zerofox":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "K7AntiVirus":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "SecureBrain":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Quttera":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "AegisLab WebGuard":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "MalwareDomainList":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site",
             "detail": "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=helenphilwarnes.com"
          },
          "ZeusTracker":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site",
             "detail": "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php?host=helenphilwarnes.com"
          },
          "zvelo":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Google Safebrowsing":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "FraudScore":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Kaspersky":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "BitDefender":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malware site"
          },
          "Opera":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malicious site"
          },
          "Certly":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "G-Data":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "C-SIRT":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "CyberCrime":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Websense ThreatSeeker":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "MalwarePatrol":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Webutation":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Trustwave":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malicious site"
          },
          "Web Security Guard":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "desenmascara.me":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "ADMINUSLabs":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Malwarebytes hpHosts":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Dr.Web":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "AlienVault":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Emsisoft":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "Malc0de Database":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site",
             "detail": "http://malc0de.com/database/index.php?search=helenphilwarnes.com"
          },
          "malwares.com URL checker":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Phishtank":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "Malwared":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Avira":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "StopBadware":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "unrated site"
          },
          "Antiy-AVL":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "SCUMWARE.org":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malware site"
          },
          "FraudSense":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Comodo Site Inspector":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Malekal":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "ESET":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "Sophos":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malicious site"
          },
          "Yandex Safebrowsing":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site",
             "detail": "http://yandex.com/infected?l10n=en&url=http://helenphilwarnes.com/ymal/image.htm"
          },
          "Spam404":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Nucleon":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Malware Domain Blocklist":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Blueliv":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Netcraft":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "malicious site"
          },
          "AutoShun":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "unrated site"
          },
          "ThreatHive":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "ParetoLogic":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Tencent":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "URLQuery":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "unrated site"
          },
          "Sucuri SiteCheck":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Fortinet":       {
             "detected": true,
             "result": "phishing site"
          },
          "ZeroCERT":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "Baidu-International":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          },
          "securolytics":       {
             "detected": false,
             "result": "clean site"
          }
       }
    };
    
    // access a single scan by key
    console.log(jsonobj.scans['securolytics'].result);
    
    // enumerate all scans
    for (var scan in jsonobj.scans) {
        console.log(scan + ': ' + jsonobj.scans[scan].result);
    }
```